# If a and b are two distinct real values such that $F (x)= x^2+ax+b $ And given that $F(a)=F(b)$ ; find the value of $F(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $a$ and$ b$ are two distinct real values such that 
>   $$F (x)= x^2+ax+b $$
>    And given that  $F(a)=F(b)$ ; find the value of $F(2)$

---

My try:

$$F(a)=a^2+a^2+b= 2a^2+b,\quad
F(b)=b^2+ab+b $$

$F(a)=F(b)$  implies   $2a^2=b^2+ab$, and thus

$F(2)= 4+2a+b $

What Now?

Any help would be appreciated , thank you

Comment: Why the `linear-algebra` tag?

Comment: @Jack what do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a^{ 2 }+{ a }^{ 2 }+b={ b }^{ 2 }+ab+b\\ { a }^{ 2 }-{ b }^{ 2 }=ab-{ a }^{ 2 }\\ \left( a-b \right) \left( a+b \right) =a\left( b-a \right) \\ \left( a-b \right) \left( a+b \right) +a\left( a-b \right) =0\\ \left( a-b \right) \left( 2a+b \right) =0\\ a\neq b,b=-2a\\ $$

Answer (score 3):

$F(2) = 2^2+2a+b = 4+2a+b$. From $2a^2 = b^2+ab \implies a^2-b^2 = ab - a^2 \implies (a-b)(a+b) = a(b-a) \implies (a-b)(2a+b) = 0\implies a = b$ or $2a+b = 0$. Since $a \neq b, 2a+b = 0 \implies F(2) = 4+0 = 4$.

Comment: thank you sir , elegant  solution

Answer (score 2):

Due to the symmetry of parabolas of that form, you can see $\frac{|a+b|}{2}$ is a minimum or maximum.

This gives you $f'\left(\frac{|a+b|}{2}\right)=|a+b|+a=0$ which implies $b=0\lor 2a+b=0$.

$b=0 \implies F(b)=0 \land F(a)=2a^2$

But $F(a)=F(b)\implies a=0$ which leads to a contradiction (as $a$ and $b$ are distinct).

Hence $2a+b=0$ as required.